# can i use adb to select a menu inside the app?

Tags: android, adb

I am successfully able to open the app using adb shell am start "package name" ...

Once the app launches, I get a menu that has "calculator" "profile" "photo"

so is there a way that i can open any menu using adb?

Comment: use a shorter question header otherwise people will not read and look at your question and what is "bunot"

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) which uses a special adb client and is able to locate and interact with Views.
See the examples that come with the source distribution.

Answer (score 0):

NO, as far as i know, you cannot do it directly from ADB